# How to mock function in react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I am new to react testing. I have following component which has api call and returns function. How to test it in react testing library?.

```
const SchoolData = (url) =>{
  
    const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState<>();
    
    const commitStudentData = () =>{
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => setStudentData(res.studentInfo))
        .catch(new Error("Error"))  
    }
    return commitStudentData;
}
```

Comment: are you looking for `const arr = [ 'arr1','arr2','arr3'] as const` ?

Comment: @tsamridh86 it need not be const